# Future return value from ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, ldap

Hello fellow programmers,

I am currently working on retrieving information from a user who works for our company

```
public class SCD_Checker {
    private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    private String mail = "";
    private String stat;


    private Connection conn = new Connection();

    SCD_Checker() {
        conn.setProvider("ADsDSOObject");
        conn.Open("Active Directory Provider", "", "", 0);
    }

    private void ldap_call(String email) {
        this.mail = email;
        Command objCmd = new Command();
        Recordset RS = new Recordset();
        objCmd.setActiveConnection(conn);
        String searchKeyword = "contractstatus";
        objCmd.setCommandText("XXX:LDAP_CONN)(mail=" + email + "));" + searchKeyword + ";subTree");

        RS = objCmd.Execute();
        if (RS.getBOF()) this.stat = "Not in SCD";
        else {
            RS.MoveFirst();
            Variant value = RS.getFields().getItem(0).getValue();

            if (value.getString().equals("R")) this.stat = "Retired";
            else if (value.getString().equals("A")) this.stat = "Active";
            else if (value.getString().equals("null")) this.stat = "Not in SCD";
        }
    }

    public void submit_task(String email) {
        this.service.submit(() -> ldap_call(email));
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return this.mail;
    }

    public String getStat() {
        return this.stat;
    }

    public void shutdown_and_close() throws InterruptedException {
        this.service.shutdown();
        this.service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        this.conn.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the code I got working until now, the problem is I seem to have it build wrong, because if I try to make a Future out of the **stat** variable, I can not save the value returned from  `Variant value = RS.getFields().getItem(0).getValue();` in the stat variable. When leaving it as a String variable, I can easily write the results into a csv file. But I would need to return a String with Email + the status.

It seems to be some error in my architecture,but I seem not be able to know how to fix the current program to correctly return the values, since none of the functions return a value.

Does anyone have an idea, how i need to change the architecture?

I might use a Callable as far as I have seen similar questions, but can't get it to work to get the values from the **ldap_call()** function

Comment: Why do you use `mail` and `stat` as shared field for whole class? Is it really works till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need adjust you architecture.

1. If you want to return multiple value from a Java function, you can
   create an assemble class, here you can create `WorkerDTO` which
   contains stat and email:

   ```
   public class WorkerDTO {

       private String email;
       private String stat;

       public String getEmail() {
           return email;
       }

       public void setEmail(String email) {
           this.email = email;
       }

       public String getStat() {
           return stat;
       }

       public void setStat(String stat) {
           this.stat = stat;
       }
   }
   ```
2. And you should extract a `Callable` class which accept an email and
   return WorkerDTO:

   ```
   public class CheckStatusCallable implements Callable<WorkerDTO> {

       private Connection connection;
       private String email;

       public CheckStatusCallable(Connection connection, String email) {
           this.connection = connection;
           this.email = email;
       }

       @Override
       public WorkerDTO call() throws Exception {
           Command objCmd = new Command();
           Recordset RS = new Recordset();
           objCmd.setActiveConnection(conn);
           String searchKeyword = "contractstatus";
           objCmd.setCommandText("XXX:LDAP_CONN)(mail=" + this.email + "));" + searchKeyword + ";subTree");

           RS = objCmd.Execute();
           WorkerDTO workerDTO = new WorkerDTO();
           workerDTO.setEmail(this.email);
           workerDTO.setEmail(e);
           if (RS.getBOF()) workerDTO.setStat("Not in SCD");
           else {
               RS.MoveFirst();
               Variant value = RS.getFields().getItem(0).getValue();

               if (value.getString().equals("R")) workerDTO.setStat("Retired");
               else if (value.getString().equals("A")) workerDTO.setStat("Active");
               else if (value.getString().equals("null")) workerDTO.setStat("Not in SCD");
           }
           return workerDTO;
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the SCD_Checker, just create new task using `CheckStatusCallable`
   and submit it to the executor.

   ```
   public class SCD_Checker {
       private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

       private Connection conn = new Connection();

       SCD_Checker() {
           conn.setProvider("ADsDSOObject");
           conn.Open("Active Directory Provider", "", "", 0);
       }

       public Future<WorkerDTO> submit_task(String email) {
           return this.service.submit(new CheckStatusCallable(conn, email));
       }

       public void shutdown_and_close() throws InterruptedException {
           this.service.shutdown();
           this.service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
           this.conn.Close();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Test if it works with:

   ```
   public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SCD_Checker checker = new SCD_Checker();
           Future<WorkerDTO> workerDTOFuture = checker.submit_task("test@test.com");
           WorkerDTO workerDTO = workerDTOFuture.get();
           String email = workerDTO.getEmail();
           String stat = workerDTO.getStat();
       }
   }
   ```